Stuck on exercise from Goldblatt's "Topoi"
On page 78 of R. Goldblatt's "Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic", the author introduces the notion of an element of a category thusly: if a category $\mathcal C$ has a terminal object $\mathbf 1$, then an element of a $\mathcal C$-object $a$ is a $\mathcal C$-arrow $x:\mathbf 1\to a$. Then he goes on to define the name of a $\mathcal C$-arrow $f:a\to b$, assuming $\mathcal C$ has exponentials. Denoting by $pr_a:{\mathbf 1}\times a\to a$ the product projection, the name of $f$ is the arrow ${}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}:{\mathbf 1}\to b^a$ that is the exponential adjoint of $f\circ pr_a$. Then ${}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}$ is the unique arrow such that $ev\circ {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\times 1_a = f\circ pr_a$. He then concludes claiming that for any $\mathcal C$-element $x:{\mathbf 1}\to a$ of $a$, $$ev \circ \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle = f \circ x,$$ where $\langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle: {\mathbb 1}\to b^a\times a$ is the product arrow. He then immediately proposes as an exercise to "prove this last statement."
Up until this point I have been able to do this book's exercises without too much hassle, but I've been stuck on this one for 2 days now. The furthest I got is the following diagram:

From this I can conclude that $$pr_a' \circ \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle = x \circ 1_1,$$ yielding $$f \circ pr_a' \circ \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle = f \circ x.$$
The claim would follow if $ev = f \circ pr_a'$, but I can't find any reason why that upper right triangle of the diagram would commute. I'd appreciate help/suggestions. Thanks.

That upper right triangle wouldn't commute even in $\mathsf{Set}$ -- the direct arrow would send $(g, x) \mapsto g(x)$, whereas the other composition would send $(g, x) \mapsto f(x)$, for $g : A \to B$ and $x : A$.

As a hint, can you come up with a morphism in the other direction $1 \to 1 \times a$ of the middle left morphism in your diagram?  Then, you can check whether you get a commutative triangle in the upper left of the middle diamond.

@DanielSchepler the obvious map in the direction you indicated is $\langle 1_{\mathbf 1}, x \rangle$, and indeed chasing the product diagrams it follows that ${}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\times 1_a \circ \langle 1_{\mathbf 1}, x \rangle = \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x \rangle$.
From that the claim will follow using $pr_a \circ \langle 1_{\mathbb 1}, x \rangle = x$.
Thanks! Whats the "proper" way to close the question? Should I reply to myself with the answer or is there a way to attribute the solution to you?

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3629148/104041

https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/topos-theory-study-group/questions

@Shaun your second link says the Team is private, says to contact Team owner and doesn't even tell me who the owner is.

Sorry about that, @purpleflyer! This is the first time I shared such a link! If you're interested in the study group, let me know; I'll try to get you in.

@Shaun you'll need their email address, then under Admin Settings > Users & Permissions > Invite Users.

@Shaun wow  I don't even know how I answered that before.  This time around I've skipped past that particular section in the book.

@purpleflyer I suggest that you post a complete answer. This brings extra visibility to the solution. Also you can then accept it as well. It is good practice to include attribution yes.

@purpleflyer It's my free SO Teams instance.  But both Shaun & I are Admins.   You could ping us in Chat exchange an email then we can have you join us   Remember not to put exactly your email address because of webcrawlers.

Solution using the hint from Daniel Schepler
We wish to show that $ev\circ\langle {}^{\lceil} f^{\rceil},x\rangle = f\circ x$.
From the universal property of exponentials we have
$$\tag{1}
f\circ pr_a = ev\circ{}^{\lceil} f^{\rceil}\times 1_a,
$$
and from the property of product arrows we have
$$\tag{2}
pr_a\circ\langle 1_{\mathbf 1}, x\rangle = x.
$$
Assume that the left triangle commutes in the following diagram (we already know the square commutes from (1)).

Then we have
\begin{align}
ev\circ \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle &= ev\circ {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\times 1_a\circ\langle 1_{\mathbb f}, x\rangle \\
&=f\circ pr_a\circ\langle 1_{\mathbf 1}, x\rangle \\
&=f\circ x. \quad\quad\mbox{(using (2))}
\end{align}
Thus is suffices to show that the left triangle from previous diagram commutes, i.e., to show that ${}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\times 1_a\circ\langle 1_{\mathbb 1}, x\rangle = \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle.$
In order to do that, consider the diagram below.

The diagram commutes by the definition of product and product map. Then from the uniqueness of the product arrow we have
\begin{align}
{}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\times 1_a\circ\langle 1_{\mathbf 1}, x\rangle&= \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}\circ 1_{\mathbf 1}, 1_a\circ x\rangle \\
&= \langle {}^{\lceil}f^{\rceil}, x\rangle.
\end{align}
