# Show $\operatorname{Hom}(1, [\cdot \times B \to C]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\cdot \times B, C)$ in a cartesian closed category?

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Consider a cartesian closed category where the exponential object is $[A \to B] = B^A$. The following kind of isomorphism is stated in [my book](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) as evident:

$\operatorname{Hom}(1, [\cdot \times B \to C]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\cdot \times B, C)$

Here $1$ should be the terminal object of the category. Why is this isomorphism evident?

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148864/exponential-objects-in-a-cartesian-closed-category-a1-cong-a

Comment: It's by definition of exponential object, isn't it?

Comment: Adjoint the hom over and use the unit isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{Hom}(1, A \times B \Rightarrow C) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(1 \times (A \times B), C) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(A \times B, C)$. The first isomorphism follows from [uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Category_theory), following exponentiation being right-adjoint to the cartesian product. The second isomorphism follows from the terminal object being the unit (up to isomorphism) for the cartesian product.